# WindowsPhone 8.1 Calendar Appointment

Tags: .net, calendar, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with WindowsPhoneApp Calendar

I have successfully created calendar and appointment in my application.
Uri links are handled and works for whole Aplication.

When I have clicked appointment in System calendar my app associated with it are terminated regardless whether appointment.uri is provided or not.

The same Uri works great via Uri Schemes App or if it is supplied in appointment.details, but in this option I dont know how to mask this URI like .

Create calendar code:

```
    private AppointmentCalendar currentAppCalendar;

    private const string calendarName = "nowapka";

    public async Task<AppointmentCalendar> CreateCalendar()
    {
        AppointmentStore AppStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);
        IReadOnlyList<AppointmentCalendar> appCalendars =
            await AppStore.FindAppointmentCalendarsAsync(FindAppointmentCalendarsOptions.IncludeHidden);

        AppointmentCalendar appCalendar = null;

        // Apps can create multiple calendars. Here app creates only one.
        if (appCalendars.Count == 0)
        {
            appCalendar = await AppStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync(calendarName);
        }
        else
        {
            appCalendar = appCalendars[0];
        }

        appCalendar.OtherAppReadAccess = AppointmentCalendarOtherAppReadAccess.Full;
        appCalendar.OtherAppWriteAccess = AppointmentCalendarOtherAppWriteAccess.SystemOnly;

        // This app will show the details for the appointment. Use System to let the system show the details.
        appCalendar.SummaryCardView = AppointmentSummaryCardView.App;

        await appCalendar.SaveAsync();
        //await ClearCalendar(appCalendar);
        return appCalendar;
    }

    public async Task AddAppointmentToCalendar()
    {
        if (currentAppCalendar == null) currentAppCalendar = await CreateCalendar();
        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment();
        try
        {
            newAppointment.StartTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Today.Hour+1, DateTime.Today.Minute+10, DateTime.Today.Second, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now));
            newAppointment.Subject = string.Format("test nowaapka ");
            newAppointment.Duration = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
            newAppointment.AllDay = false;
            newAppointment.Reminder = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
            newAppointment.Details = "nowapka://pivotpage/?number=2138138";
            newAppointment.Sensitivity = AppointmentSensitivity.Private;
            newAppointment.BusyStatus = AppointmentBusyStatus.Busy;
            newAppointment.Uri = new Uri("nowapka://pivotpage/?number=2138138");
            await currentAppCalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(newAppointment);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {

        }
    }
```

handle uri in app code:

```
    protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active.
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page.
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            // Associate the frame with a SuspensionManager key.
            SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");

            // TODO: Change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application.
            rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

            // Set the default language
            rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // Restore the saved session state only when appropriate.
                try
                {
                    await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
                }
                catch (SuspensionManagerException)
                {
                    // Something went wrong restoring state.
                    // Assume there is no state and continue.
                }
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window.
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
            if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    this.transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter.
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(PivotPage), e))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active.
        Window.Current.Activate();
        base.OnActivated(e);
    }
```

Can anybody help solve this problem? Maybe it's frequent issue with windowsPhone calendar?